# VueJS + VUEX + Firebase: Where To Hook Up Firebase?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuex

I would like to integrate **Firebase** in my **Vue.JS** app.

I wonder WHERE to put the **references** to Firebase.

Comment: I'd recommend you to check this plugin: https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire

Comment: I don't want to use this plugin ... it doesn't work well with VUEX and Vuexfire doesn't work with Firebase 4!! :(

Answer (score 43):

To install firebase as a dependency in your project `cd` into your project directory and run the following command in the command line

```
npm install --save firebase
```

Now in your main.js file add this

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import { store } from './store/store'


const config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxx"
  };

firebase.initializeApp(config);
Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

- you can also add your firebase credentials in an external js file and import it in the main.js file as follows:

**firebase-config.js**

```
export const config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxx"
  };
```

Now in your main.js do as follows

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import { store } from './store/store'
import { config } from './firebase-config'

firebase.initializeApp(config);
Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

- adding firebase to the `Vue.prototype` allows usage of firebase in your vue components by using `this.$firebase`
- if you don't want this behavior you can just initialize firebase using `firebase.initializeApp(config);`
- now coming to your vuex store you can just import the firebase module as below

  ```
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import Vuex from 'vuex'
  import * as firebase from 'firebase'

  Vue.use(Vuex);

  export const store = new Vuex.Store({
      state:{},
      mutations:{},
      actions:{
          myFirebaseAction: ({commit}) => {
              //you can use firebase like this
              var ref = firebase.database().ref()
          }
      }
  });
  ```

Credits to [@umang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345813/umang) for suggesting to add the `firebase` global namespace to the `Vue.prototype` instead of the firebase app instance.

Comment: up voted for this `Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase.initializeApp(config);`.

Comment: same! I really like how it exposes it to all the components for ease of use.

Comment: Where would you place any validation before saving the action? In the mutation? Component method or action itself?

Comment: @Notflip could not completely understand your question...could you be more specefic

Comment: For example checking if a field is not an empty string, or an input field is an integer, where would you put that logic? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @VamsiKrishna This doesn't work for me. It seems whenever I `import * as firebase from 'firebase'` in my vuex modules, i get the app/no-app error from firebase stating that there is no firebase app initialized. Does ordering of the module imports matter?

Comment: @bdeo did you  initialise the firebase app

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I was able to resolve this by initializing the app in a separate file and explicitly exporting the app and then importing that app instead of the firebase module with import firebase from “firebase” in my store

Comment: How do you resolve `new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()` using this method? `new this.$firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()` is not working

Comment: This is almost the right answer. As @jeand'arme pointed out, you can't access `firebase.auth.blah` or `firebase.firestore.blah`, but *can* access `firebase.auth().blah` and `firebase.firestore().blah`. It can be fixed with `firebase.initializeApp(config); Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase;` You are still initializing firebase, but are storing the class not the instance (I don't know the JS terminology for this)

Comment: @Umang good one umang **: -)**. Adding the `firebase` namespace on the Vue prototype is a better idea instead of the firebase app instance

Comment: @VamsiKrishna: Ah, namespace was the term I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: im using this approach and i got this error in components this.$firebase.collection is not a function @Umang