# AuthProvider is not a constructor when using firebase auth, VueJS Webpack

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I'm currently using Vue JS Webpack template to build my app. Everytime I try to login using one of the auth provider I get the following error :

> Login.vue?a071:44 Uncaught TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__firebaseApp**.a.auth.GoogleAuthProvider is not a constructor

here are the relevant parts of my code :
my firebase config file

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
let config = {
  apiKey : 'xxxxxxx',
  authDomain: 'xxxxxx',
  databaseURL: 'xxxxxxx',
  projectId: 'yyyyyy'
}
export default firebase.initializeApp(config)
```

and my Login.Vue login method

```js
<template>
 <div class="login">
  <div v-if="loading" class="modal-loading-white">
   <img class="loader-img" src="/img/loader-gray.svg">
  </div>
  <div>Login</div>
  <div v-show="this.errorMsg">{{ errorMsg }}</div>
  <div><label>Email </label>: <input type="email" v-model.trim="emailForm"/></div><br>
  <div><label>Password </label>: <input type="password" v-model.trim="passwordForm"/></div><br>
  <button v-on:click="logInUserWithProvider('email')">Login</button><br>
  <div><router-link to="forgot">Forget Your Password?</router-link></div>
  <button v-on:click="logInUserWithProvider('google')">Google</button>
  <button v-on:click="logInUserWithProvider('facebook')">Facebook</button>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  import firebase from '../firebaseApp'
  export default {
 name: 'loginForm',
 data: function () {
  return {
   emailForm:'',
   passwordForm: '',
   errorMsg: '',
   loading: false
  }
 },
 methods: {
  logInUserWithEmail: function() {
   if (this.emailForm && this.passwordForm) {
    this.loading = true;
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.emailForm, this.passwordForm).catch(function (error) {
     this.errorMsg = error.message;
     this.loading = false;
    }.bind(this));
   } else {
    this.errorMsg = 'Email and password can\'t be empty';
   }
  },
  logInUserWithProvider: function(provider) {
   if (provider == 'google') {
    var authProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    this.loading = true;
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(authProvider);
   } else if (provider == 'facebook') {
    var authProvider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    this.loading = true;
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(authProvider);
   } else if (provider == 'email') {
    this.logInUserWithEmail();
   }

   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {     
     this.emailForm = '';
     this.passwordForm = '';
     this.$emit('login');
    }
   });
  }
 } 
  }
</script>
```

Comment: could you provide complete Login.vue file?

Comment: @Follio I've added the complete code for Login.vue

Comment: is your firebase config file named firebaseApp.js?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44353652/7814783 . You can setup firebase to the `Vue.prototype` and use firebase anywhere in your components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you were trying to import is config data container.
Change your firebase config file to

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
let config = {
  apiKey : 'xxxxxxx',
  authDomain: 'xxxxxx',
  databaseURL: 'xxxxxxx',
  projectId: 'yyyyyy'
}
firebase.initializeApp(config)
export default firebase
```